# Don't touch jQuery when you add new form

Tags: php, jquery, html

Let's say I have an input: `<input type="text" id="smth" value="" />` and I have jQuery to pass this data to .php file

```
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
        var info = {};
        info['smth'] = $('#smth').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(msg){
                alert("Well done!");
            }
        })
})
```

It works great, but let's say I need to add new input, let's say:

`<input type="text" id="smth2" value="" />`,

so I need in jQuery add this line after `info['smth']`:

`info['smth2'] = $('#smth2').val();`.

My question is, how can I avoid this? Is it possible to not add new line in jQuery every time I add new input? How would it look like? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hopefully, you're adding all your `<input>`s to a `<form>`. Hopefully, all those `<input>`s have `name` attributes (eg your first one should have `name="smth"`). In this case, the problem is solved for you!

```
var info = $('#myForm').serialize();
```

Done!